# find users that are following other users

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I'm wondering how I can go about this problem

I have a DB with a Users Table, and a Followers table.
The Followers table contains 2 Columns "FollowerID" and "FollowedID"
I have a 1 -> * relation in my datamodel between `Users.ID -> Followers.FollowerID` and `Users.ID -> FollowedID`

How do I in LINQ get a set of users that are following a specific user?

I'll express what I'm trying to achieve programatically 
I can get this far:

```
ctx.Followers.Where(f => f.FollowedID == CurrentUser.ID)
```

so now i have a Followers set where I have the ID of the users that follow the CurrentUser, and I could iterate through this collection and then add users after each iteration to a collection that would be a total USER collection that followed CurrentUser, but isn't there a smarter, or LINQ'er way to do this?

Much appreciated

Thx

Comment: Now I can see why twitter has so many production problems.

Comment: Hehe Zombies :D thx for editing my post Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ctx.Followers.Where(f => f.FollowedID == CurrentUser.UserId)
             .Select(f => f.FollowerUser).Distinct()
```

If you have an EntityRef for the FollowerID (example name FollewerUser) you can use this to get all users following a particular ID

Comment: I see, but then how do I get an entityreference for a user? I thought, I'd do this with the relationship, but all I have is the ID

Comment: Are you using LINQ-To-SQL or EntityFramework?  With LINQ-To-SQL you need to setup a foreign key relationship in your DBML.  I believe EF is similar but not really sure.

Comment: I was using the EntityFramework, because of a Domain Service, but I think I'll just switch to LINQ-To-SQL as I know that better aswell